# Find multicast outgoing interface

Tags: python, regex, multicast

Been trying to regex the following but so far have failed.

Trying to catch a multicast bug in a router. The bug is a multicast where the outgoing interface is a Bundle-Ether(ether bundles only) and is not correlated to a physical linecard.

Example output is below:

```
(192.168.72.140,232.95.240.51) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.89 Flags: RPF
  Up: 4w4d
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether20 Flags: A, Up: 4w4d
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 (0/0/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d

(192.168.137.7,232.95.240.68) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.242 Flags: RPF
  Up: 20:50:13
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 Flags: A, Up: 20:50:13
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether20 (0/2/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 20:50:13

(192.168.137.12,232.95.240.71) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.242 Flags: RPF
  Up: 4w4d
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 Flags: A, Up: 23:09:53
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether12 (0/8/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d
    Bundle-Ether20 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37
    Bundle-Ether429 (0/7/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d
```

You will notice that the last multicast (S,G = 192.168.137.12,232.95.240,71) has a Bundle-Ether, in the outgoing interface, where is goes directly from the interface to the "Flags". In this case "Bundle-Ether20 Flags:". While the interface of "Bundle-Ether429 (0/7/CPU0) Flags:" is not hitting the bug.

Trying to figure out how I only catch the multicasts that hit this bug and ignore the rest since my output can be thousands of line. Should I split the output into separate line and run a loop to process each line (and have nested loops for conditional matches)? Was hoping there was a Regex solution, preferably in python.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean by `where is goes directly from the interface to the "Flags". In this case "Bundle-Ether20 Flags:". While the interface of "Bundle-Ether429 (0/7/CPU0) Flags:" is not hitting the bug.` Can you tell which lines should match. And the condition to match?

Comment: It is a nested problem. First is the multicast source and group (192.168.1.1,232.0.0.0) for example. Then within that body of text you have to find the "Outgoing Interface List". The you have to find every interface (until the next multicast group or end of data) that says "Bundle-Ether" but does not have a piece of data mentioning the linecard (0/0/CPU0 in one example) between the interface name that the text says "Flags:". That text is on the same line as the Bundle-Ether name.

Comment: Could have tried to construct the regex, but not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I believe I could do with nested conditionals/loops but was hoping there was a less complex solution.

Comment: You mean where there is no tuple like `(0/8/CPU0)` like in `Bundle-Ether20 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37` ?

Comment: MYGz: correct. But I only want to match that when a "Outgoing" interface. And when I do I have to know what multicast group it is part of.

Comment: Check. You can try along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the current input that you gave. It will work if the format remains the same throughout. If the format changes you can fine tune it. Let's make the input a bit more diverse and test our code:

#### Input File: file.log

```
(192.168.72.140,232.95.240.51) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.89 Flags: RPF
  Up: 4w4d
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether20 Flags: A, Up: 4w4d
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 (0/0/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d

(192.168.137.7,232.95.240.68) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.242 Flags: RPF
  Up: 20:50:13
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 Flags: A, Up: 20:50:13
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether2011 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37

(192.168.137.12,232.95.240.71) RPF nbr: 10.0.34.242 Flags: RPF
  Up: 4w4d
  Incoming Interface List
    Bundle-Ether5 Flags: A, Up: 23:09:53
  Outgoing Interface List
    Bundle-Ether12 (0/8/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d
    Bundle-Ether20 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37
    Bundle-Ether429 (0/7/CPU0) Flags: F NS, Up: 4w4d
    Bundle-Ether204 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37
```

#### Code:

```
import re

with open(file.log, 'r') as f:
    for entry in f.read().split('\n\n'):
        req2=[]
        req = entry.split()
        req2.append(req[0])
        i = req.index('Outgoing')+3
        req2.append(req[i:])
        res = re.findall(r'Bundle-Ether\d+\s*[^(]+?(?=Bundle-Ether|$)',' '.join(req2[1]))
        if res:
            req3= [req2[0]] + res
            print req3
```

#### Output:

```
['(192.168.137.7,232.95.240.68)', 'Bundle-Ether2011 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37']
['(192.168.137.12,232.95.240.71)', 'Bundle-Ether20 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37 ', 'Bundle-Ether204 Flags: F NS, Up: 23:09:37']
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks MYGz. Will give it a spin.

Comment: I think you will have to adjust the Regex in re.findall if the last bundle ether is erroneous. I am going to sleep, if you fail to fine tune it, edit the question for the cases it's not working, I'll check in morning.

Comment: For you to answer after you get some shuteye: In your findall where is your regex for the group/multicast? I am going to replicate your code and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DJOtter Ok, The regex is fixed now.  The multicast group is the first element in the `req` i.e `entry.split()` so we pick it like `req[0]` and don't need a regex for that.

Comment: @DJOtter If the code works [consider accepting the answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)